# use of lapply() or map() from purrr package to extract names of list elements

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

I am trying to use the `lapply` or `map` from `purrr` to retrieve the names from a list as part of a larger function I am building, but I keep getting an unexpected result.  For example:

```
MyList=list(x=1:5, y=6:10)

> MyList
$x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$y
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

names(MyList)
[1] "x" "y"
### seems OK

map(MyList,names)
$x
NULL

$y
NULL

map_chr(MyList,names)
Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector
```

`lapply()` gives the same results as `map()`. The object I am getting back is a `list`, the elements of which have the names I want, but the contents of each element is `NULL`. I would like to extract the names themselves, either as elements in a list or as a character vector. Why is this happening? How should I accomplish this?

Comment: `names(MyList)`?  It is `MyList` that has names.  The contents of `MyList`, `MyList$x` and `MyList$y` don't have names.

Comment: @BrodieG Thanks - I was being an idiot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunetely, there is no way to get element names using `map` or `lapply`. When I'm using a custom function in `map` or `lapply` that requires the element name I'll `map` over a vector of m element names and then pull data from a list using that. Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr) 
library(purrr)

MyList = list(Normal = rnorm(1000), 
              Gamma = rgamma(1000, shape = 4), 
              Weibull = rweibull(1000, shape = 1))

ListNames <- names(MyList)

ListNames %>% 
  walk(function(x) { # walk is another version of map
    data <- MyList[[x]]
    cat("\nMean of ", x, "is ", mean(data))
    cat("\nMedian of ", x, "is ", median(data))
  })
```

Which  gives:

```
Mean of  Normal is  0.03043051
Median of  Normal is  0.01864171
Mean of  Gamma is  3.884722
Median of  Gamma is  3.500294
Mean of  Weibull is  0.9854814
Median of  Weibull is  0.6707907
```